# iOS webview strange issue / webview is null after operation

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm writing an application to loading images from website using data as json. There is 2 queue - main and waiting queue. I'm sure they're works fine, content is downloading properly but when im switching between queue **first post doesn't load at all** (when i swipe one post and back to the first post then it load properly). I made NSLog all my function. When i swipe to next picture its looks like

```
2014-03-14 12:09:15.019 xx[2509:60b] checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost
2014-03-14 12:09:15.021 xx[2509:60b] displayPostImage
2014-03-14 12:09:15.022 xx[2509:60b] displayPostImage - END
2014-03-14 12:09:15.023 xx[2509:60b] displayTitleAndDescriptionLabel
2014-03-14 12:09:15.024 xx[2509:60b] displayNumberOfPointsAndComments
2014-03-14 12:09:15.025 xx[2509:60b] configureLikeButton
2014-03-14 12:09:15.032 xx[2509:60b] webViewDidStartLoad
2014-03-14 12:09:15.454 xx[2509:60b] webViewDidFinishLoad
```

but when i'm change the queue first post looks like:

```
2014-03-14 12:09:15.019 xx[2509:60b] checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost
2014-03-14 12:09:15.021 xx[2509:60b] displayPostImage
2014-03-14 12:09:15.022 xx[2509:60b] displayPostImage - END
2014-03-14 12:09:15.023 xx[2509:60b] displayTitleAndDescriptionLabel
2014-03-14 12:09:15.024 xx[2509:60b] displayNumberOfPointsAndComments
2014-03-14 12:09:15.025 xx[2509:60b] configureLikeButton
```

My methods:

```
-(void)loadPostsAndDisplayPostContent:(void (^)(BOOL finished)) completion{
    [[MyApi client] loadPosts:^(BOOL isSuccess) {
        if(isSuccess){

            // DEBUG
            NSLog(@"loadPostsAndDisplayPostContent");

            _currentPost = [[MyApi client] getCurrentPostFromBundleOfPosts];
            NSLog(@"%@", _currentPost.link);
            [self checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost];
            [self displayTitleAndDesciptionLabel];
            [self displayNumberOfPointsAndComments];
            [self configureLikeButton];
            completion(YES);
        }else{
            completion(NO);
        }
    }];
}

-(void)checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost{

    // DEBUG
    NSLog(@"checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost");

    if ([_currentPost.type isEqualToString:@"image"])
        [self displayPostImage];
    else if ([_currentPost.type isEqualToString:@"movie"])
        [self setUpVideoPlayButton];
}

-(void)displayPostImage{

    // DEBUG
    NSLog(@"displayPostImage");

    [_galleryButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_webView loadHTMLString:
     [UUUHelperMethods configureImageDimensions:_currentPost.image] baseURL:nil];

    // DEBUG
    NSLog(@"displayPostImage - END");
}

#pragma mark swipe recognizer 

- (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender {
    _currentPost = [[MyApi client] getPreviousPostFromBundleOfPosts];
    [self checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost];
    [UIWebView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [UIWebView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIWebView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.webView cache:NO];
    }];
    [self displayTitleAndDesciptionLabel];
    [self displayNumberOfPointsAndComments];
    [self configureLikeButton];
}

- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender {
    _currentPost = [[MyApi client] getNextPostFromBundleOfPosts];
    [self checkPostTypeAndDisplayPost];
    [UIWebView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [UIWebView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIWebView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.webView cache:NO];
    }];
    [self displayTitleAndDesciptionLabel];
    [self displayNumberOfPointsAndComments];
    [self configureLikeButton];
}

#pragma mark webview delegate methods 

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    // DEBUG≠
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");

    _webView.hidden = YES;
    [SVProgressHUD show];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    // DEBUG
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");

    _webView.hidden = NO;
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

and HelperMethod to configure dimensions:

```
+(NSString *)configureImageDimensions:(NSURL*)pictureURL{
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"<html>"
                            "<head>"
                            "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >"
                            "function display(img){"
                            "var imgOrigH = document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight;"
                            "var imgOrigW = document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth;"
                            "var bodyH = window.innerHeight;"
                            "var bodyW = window.innerWidth;"
                            "if((imgOrigW/imgOrigH) > (bodyW/bodyH))"
                            "{"
                            "document.getElementById('image').style.width = bodyW + 'px';"
                            "document.getElementById('image').style.top = (bodyH - document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight)/2  + 'px';"
                            "}"
                            "else"
                            "{"
                            "document.getElementById('image').style.height = bodyH + 'px';"
                            "document.getElementById('image').style.marginLeft = (bodyW - document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth)/2  + 'px';"
                            "}"
                            "}"
                            "</script>"
                            "</head>"
                            "<body style=\"margin:0;width:100%%; height:100%%;  \" >"
                            "<img id=\"image\" src=\"%@\" onload=\"display()\" style=\"position:relative\" />"
                            "</body>"
                            "</html>",pictureURL
                            ];

    return htmlString;
}
```

I'm sure the methods works fine because it works with iOS6. After some changes and transfer to iOS7 it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT1: I tried call Display Image one more time after loading post complete but it didn't work.

EDIT2:  My webview after switch queue is null. Any idea how to fix it?

SOLUTION: I know, it's old thread but maybe some1 has the same issue. The best way to fix this is add NSNotification at main class, not loading webViews from another class. I don't belive how stupid I was. Have fun!

Comment: is something interesting in `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` ?

Comment: Nope, webView:didFailLoadWithError: is not call.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use Safari developer tools, and see what content loaded, and may be some helpful logs in console

Comment: no, is just Safari tool, to use it you need enable developer menu, and connect Web inspector to UIWebView in simulator or iDevice

Comment: can you add more logs in `displayPostImage`? please add `NSLog(@"webView: %@", _webView);` and in `configureImageDimensions` `NSLog(@"url: %@", pictureURL);` after done please update your question with new logs.

Comment: I found the problem. Webview is null after change queue. Any idea how to fix it? (pictureURL is correct)

Comment: I glad to help), about webView, from code you posted is hard to say, show where/how you create webView?

Comment: My webView is property (CTRL + drag). I called some methods in viewDidLoad like delegate, scrollView, and scalesPageToFit. I didn't allocate it manually.